# Method for storing complex property in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

In my code, I have a `Chats` model which stored information about  a `Chat`. It includes the `users` in the chat as well as other information such as `createdAt` and `updatedAt`.

I also have a `Message` model which has properties relating to the message such as `sentBy` as well as `messageText`.

Users can star/save messages and then view all of the starred messages that they have for a particular `Chat`

The problem I have is knowing where to store this information. In the `Chat` or `Messages` model.

If stored in the `Chat` model then the structure would look like so.

```
ChatObj: {
   users: [UserIds],
   createdAt: Date,
   updatedAt: Date,
   chatTitle: String,
   starredMessages: {
      UserID1: [
         StarredMessageId1,
         StarredMessageId2
      ],
      UserID2: [
         StarredMessageId1,
         StarredMessageId2
      ],
   } 
}
```

`starredMessages`would contain the `UserId` as a key, and an `array` of all starred message id's as a value.

An alternative is to store `starredMessages` in the `Messages` model. This would look like this:

```
MessageObj: {
   sentBy: [UserId],
   text: String,
   starredBy: [userIds]
}
```

The message object would simply contain an array of user id's whom have starred that particular message

**When retrieving all messages that a user has starred for a particular chat**, it would be much more efficient using option 1, as you would simply look up the `key` which is the `user id` in order to get all the results. With option 2, you would have to search through all the message objects (could be dozens), to see if the `user id` is present in the `starredBy` array.

Is it correct to assume method 1 would be more appropriate due to the reason described above (more efficient), or would option 2 make more sense in terms of where to store this information regarding `starred messages` Thanks.